# Why does this XML attribute fire a validation error and why is it even there?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I create an xml-fil and run into a problem. I have simplified my code as much as I can to show the error. I have a reference to Microsoft XML 6.0 in my project. When I run this code

```
Sub simpleTest()
    Dim xDoc As New DOMDocument60
    Dim n0 As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim n1 As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim n2 As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim blValiderad As Boolean
    Const file = "c:\temp\abc.xml"
    
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.validateOnParse = False
    xDoc.resolveExternals = False
    xDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True
    Set n0 = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
    xDoc.appendChild n0
    Set n1 = xDoc.createElement("Document")
    n1.setAttribute "xmlns", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    n1.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Set n2 = xDoc.createElement("CstmrCdtTrfInitn")
    n2.Text = "hello"
    n1.appendChild n2  'CstmrCdtTrfInitn
    xDoc.appendChild n1 'Document
    xDoc.Save file
End Sub
```

it produces this xml-expression

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn xmlns="">
hello
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

On validation it produces this error:

> 1072897501; Validate failed because the document does not contain
> exactly one root node.

The problem seems to be the empty attribute **xmlns=""** of CstmrCdtTrfInitn. When I remove it from the file there is no validation errors. Why is that and why is it even produced by my code?

Comment: I did not get any <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> when I removed the line with createProcessingInstruction.

Comment: Hm... version 1.0 and encoding UTF-8 are the defaults, they don't really need to be declared, so it's still fine without that line. But you're right, this seems to be the only way to force MSXML to write the XML declaration, or save the file as something *other* than UTF-8. Never mind my comment then.

Comment: How are you validating the XML output?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, `CreateElement("some_text")` is a shorthand for `createNode(Type:=NODE_ELEMENT, Name:="some_text", NamespaceURI:="")`.

Since that NamespaceURI doesn't match the parent element, the attribute gets created.

Instead, use `createNode` and specify the namespace:

```
Dim xDoc As New DOMDocument60
Dim n0 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim n1 As IXMLDOMElement
Dim n2 As IXMLDOMElement
Dim blValiderad As Boolean
Const file = "c:\temp\abc.xml"

xDoc.async = False
xDoc.validateOnParse = False
xDoc.resolveExternals = False
xDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True
Set n0 = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
xDoc.appendChild n0
Set n1 = xDoc.createElement("Document")
n1.setAttribute "xmlns", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
n1.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
Set n2 = xDoc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "CstmrCdtTrfInitn", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")
n2.Text = "hello"
n1.appendChild n2  'CstmrCdtTrfInitn
xDoc.appendChild n1 'Document
Debug.Print xDoc.XML
```

Comment: The `<Document>` node ought to be created with the namespace URI as well.

Comment: Yup, it's appended after creating which isn't harmful per se, just more complicated than needed